# how to convert ISO 8601 date if day goes before month?

Tags: php, date

I have date '1987-24-06T00:00:00.000+06:00' where format is 'Y-d-m', when i try to

```
strtotime('1987-24-06T00:00:00.000+06:00') //return false
```

it return false because of day before month. If I do

```
strtotime('1987-11-06T00:00:00.000+06:00') // return 563133600
```

it works fine.

Is there any option to make it work?

Comment: It's not ISO-8601 if day precedes month, it's custom. Have a look at [DateTime's `createfromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php) method.

Comment: You can't programmatically figure out if `1987-12-01` is `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-DD-MM`. Do you really need so? Do you know the format in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned @El_Vanja, I used createfromFormat, so my code looks like

```
$date = '1987-24-06T00:00:00.000+06:00';
$dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-d-m\TH:i:s.uP", $date)->format('Y-d-m H:i'); // 1988-12-06 00:00
```

Comment: This is reading the day as a month and vice versa. You need to use `Y-d-m\TH:i:s.uP`.

Comment: ... and that's why it adds a extra year to comply with the 24 months.

Comment: It's create *from* format, not create *in* format. Meaning you need to tell it what kind of format you're passing to it, and that's what @Phylogenesis pointed out.